# Send All Errors to Front-end

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a Shiny app, but the front-end is actually entirely written in HTML and JavaScript. If any error occurs on the server-side, I would like to simply send its message to the front-end. I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
options(shiny.error = function() {
  error_message <- geterrmessage()
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'display-error', message = error_message)
})
```

The problem with this approach is that `session` will not be known within the error handling function. Also, even if this were not the case, it overwrites global options.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474538/possible-to-show-console-messages-written-with-message-in-a-shiny-ui

Comment: I think this would help for one particular error but not for all errors.

Answer (score 1):

You always can use `getDefaultReactiveDomain` to get the `session` object. Furthermore, you can set the options within your shiny app and reset it via `onStop`.

Here is a POC.

```r
library(shiny)

js <- HTML("
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('catch-error', function(message) {
    alert('error caught:' + message.msg)
  })
")

ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$head(tags$script(js)),
   actionButton("err", "Create Error")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   op <- options(shiny.error = function() {
      session <- getDefaultReactiveDomain()
      error_message <- geterrmessage()
      session$sendCustomMessage("catch-error", list(msg = error_message))
   })
   print(getOption("shiny.error"))
   
   onStop(function() options(op))
   
   observeEvent(input$err, {
      stop("something bad happened")
   })
}

print(getOption("shiny.error"))
shinyApp(ui, server)
print(getOption("shiny.error"))
```

You can see that a click on `Create Error` raises an **R** error, which is however, handled on the JS side (by a simply `alert` in this case).

Furthermore, after the app closes your options are as they were before the start.

N.B. The app will stop nonetheless, due to `stop`, but as you can see the error handler is called.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!