# Display R console error messages in browser console

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that's throwing a 'disconnected from server' generic error message on load when uploaded to an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu. The app works locally and on shinyapps. When I check the logs on shiny-server there are no error messages. What I want to do is display any errors which would display in the RStudio IDE console when running the app locally, in the browser console. How can I achieve this? I've tried following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474538/possible-to-show-console-messages-written-with-message-in-a-shiny-ui), but nothing shows in the browser. I also want it to print any errors that may occur from packages, etc.

Comment: to be able to do this you need to have an established connection between the browser and the server. If the problem lays in the app start then it will happen before any attempt to communicate with the browser and so no luck to display anything in the browser console.